# Magento2 custom collection invalid method exception

Tags: magento2, collection, exception

I made a custom **CRUD** Module and when i call the collection without the `addFieldToFilter` function everything works fine but when i try to filter the collection i get the exception

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method
>   Vendor\Module\Model\AgencyProduct::addFieldToFilter

```
namespace Zweygart\Agency\Block;

/**
 * Class Stock
 * @package Zweygart\Agency\Block
 */
class Stock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $agencyDataFactory;
    protected $agencyProductFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Zweygart\Agency\Model\AgencyDataFactory $agencyDataFactory,
        \Zweygart\Agency\Model\AgencyProductFactory $agencyProductFactory
    ) {
        $this->agencyDataFactory = $agencyDataFactory;
        $this->agencyProductFactory = $agencyProductFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function getAgencysWithInventory() {

        $productCollection = $this->agencyProductFactory
            ->create();
            //->addFieldToFilter('zw_agency_product_id', 1);
        foreach($productCollection as $product) {
            die("Gnarf");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to get collection the following way:

```
$productCollection = $this->agencyProductFactory->create()
       ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('zw_agency_product_id', 1);
```

Comment: Oh man my falt thx so much.  Didn't see the missing get collection.